# Does the unit test needs to be in the same directory as the source for coverage?

Tags: sonarqube, coverage.py

Does the unit test needs to be in the same directory as the source for coverage? Would it be possible to have the unit tests in different package?

Answer (score 1):

You can have the unit test in a different package.
However you need to follow some rules.

Lets say you have the Product class under src/java/main to be tested in the following package

A.B.Product

And your unit test class ProductTest under src/test/main has to be in one of the following packages

A.B.ProductTest,  A.B.C.ProductTest, or A.B.C.ProductTest

Your unit test class ProductTest will not work if it is in one of the followinh directories

A.ProductTest , A.D.ProductTest or E.F.ProductTest

General rule is unit test class need to be in the same package or subpackage of the class to be tested